# Objective-C - JSON format for Core Data relationship like in MySQL - Best practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, core-data

I have JSON like:

```
{
    cities: {
        1: "London",
        3: "New York",
        9: "Tokio",
        10: "Moscow"
    },
    keywords: {
        120: "walk",
        121: "run",
        122: "eat",
        123: "lake"
    },
    parks: [
            {
                id: "1",
                likes: "5",
                parkName: "Park 1 in NEW YORK",
                city: "3", // id of the City NEW YORK
                keywords: [
                            "120",
                            "121"
                          ]
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                likes: "678",
                parkName: "Park 2 in NEW YORK",
                city: "3", // id of the City NEW YORK
                keywords: [
                            "120",
                            "123"
                          ]
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                likes: "416",
                parkName: "Park in London",
                city: "1", // id of the City London
                keywords: [
                            "123",
                            "122"
                          ]
            }, 
            ... so many ...
          ]
    }
}
```

So, in Xcode, I wanna use like this:
[sample Xcode Core Data relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhXhe.png)

I create NSManagedObject Subclass, and I have this methods:

```
- (void)addParksObject:(PKParks *)value;
- (void)removeParksObject:(PKParks *)value;
- (void)addParks:(NSSet<PKParks *> *)values;
```

But, I was expecting to connect Parks table to another tables like in MySQL, using **id** of the Cities and Keywords. 
So, 
I have a lot of Parks, some Cities and Keywords.

Is this way to storage data correct method?

1. Should I store **ID**s of the Cities and Keywords?
2. Should I connect tables manually, like in MySQL?
3. Should I change JSON format to no IDs?

For example JSON:

```
 {
    parks: [
            {
                id: "1",
                likes: "5",
                parkName: "Park 1 in NEW YORK",
                city: "NEW YORK", 
                keywords: [
                            "walk",
                            "run"
                          ]
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                likes: "678",
                parkName: "Park 2 in NEW YORK",
                city: "NEW YORK", 
                keywords: [
                            "walk",
                            "lake"
                          ]
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                likes: "416",
                parkName: "Park in London",
                city: "London",
                keywords: [
                            "lake",
                            "eat"
                          ]
            }, 
            ... so many ...
          ]
    }
}
```

Comment: CoreData if you haven't gone ahead and changed the persistent store is a sqlite file. You might be aware of the fact that Sqlite does not have primary and foreign key constraints or referential integrity constraints by default. CoreData's relationship is a work around to solve that. When you connected cities to park table you created a one to many relationship between city and parks. So whenever you fetch a city object to your managedObject context the city object's parks property will have an array of all parks associated with it. So whats the confusion?

Comment: When you add a park you would add it with some City object using something like cityObject.parks = set of parks with your current one :) so obviously core data is aware of which park is associated with city it maintains a id (similar to primary key and foreign key internally to which you dont have access to if you open up sqlite file you will see a column named Z_PK,Z_FK ) and you dont have to map any id to anything to link two managed objects manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, I was expecting to connect Parks table to another tables like in MySQL, using id of the Cities and Keywords.

This is the classic mistake of thinking that Core Data is like SQL. It *uses* SQLite, but SQL-style thinking will get you into trouble.

Core Data is intended to save instances of your model objects. Those objects might have properties which are also model objects. That's a Core Data relationship. You don't use foreign keys or object IDs to represent the relationship, you use model object properties. Core Data translates that to/from SQL.

You might want to read a little about [how Core Data relationships work](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1).